# Does this data imply sublinear, linear or superlinear convergence?

Tags: convergence

I know the definition of sublinear and superlinear convergence but I have some data which seems to be neither sublinear nor superlinear (unless I am mistaken).

Sublinear convergence:

$e_{k+1}/e_{k}=\mu$, $\mu_k \rightarrow 1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

Superlinear convergence:

$e_{k+1}/e_{k}=\mu$, $\mu_k \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

In the data below the algorithm seems to take a big step and it seems like $\mu_k \rightarrow 0$ is going to be the outcome but on the next iteration it takes a tiny step and it seems like $\mu_k \rightarrow 1$ will be the outcome. In the end it does reach zero but there is no consistency in the step size.

I am using Steihaug's algorithm to minimise the Rosenbrock function and this is the results I got for $e_{k+1}/e_{k}$:

$k=7$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}= 0.934232861$

$k=10$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}= 0.807544694$

$k=13$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.995838549$

$k=16$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.452339157$

$k=19$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.992655865$

$k=22$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0$

and for an alternative starting point:

$k=1$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.998526056$

$k=2$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.450931428$

$k=3$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.999459451$

$k=4$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.063103406$

$k=5$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.984516892$

$k=6$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.004744525$

$k=7$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0.990032974$

$k=8$, $e_{k+1}/e_{k}=0$

So my question to you mathoverflow guys is, what kind of convergence does this data suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Just plot your data in R with the following code:

```
plot(c(k,k2),c(r,r2),col=c(rep("blue",6),rep("red",8)))
```

Which produces:

[image]

Your first example is the blue points, your second example the red points.  It is really to few points to say much, in the first (blue) case convergence cannot possibly be better that linear, in the second case, nothing much can be said.